# What is Anitspyware Soft? How do you remove it?

Tags: windows-vista, anti-virus, spyware, anti-spyware

I think my PC has been infected by something!  IE does not work:  "Internet Explorer Warning - visiting this web site may harm your computer!"  Pop-ups are pointing me to [http://wareprotect.net/support](http://www.google.com) to buy Antispyware Soft.  What happened?  What should I do?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Remove the link so that people don't unwittingly click on it!

Comment: Don't worry, it links to google

Answer (score 0):

You can also download process explorer (http://live.sysinternals.com) procexp.exe. It is a tool from 2 russian developers, who have been acquired by microsoft.

The nice thing about process explorer is that you can use the vizor-icon to point to a visible window and it will give you the process it belongs to. Then you can kill the process(tree). You can also lookup the process info on the web, wich will eventually tell you what the process does.